# Get current month record except today's record in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I select Current Month records from a table except today's record.

My existing query is

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

The above query fetch all the current months records.. How can i edit that query to get records except today's record.

Comment: Add this to your WHERE clause:  AND DATE(columnName) <> DATE(CURRENT_DATE())

Comment: Yes its working @SloanThrasher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE columnName>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND columnName<DATE(NOW())
```

Above query will work for current month only